# Losing focus of fixed navigation in mobile safari with iOS5

Tags: jquery, focus, ios5, mobile-safari, fixed

I am in the process of optimizing a client website for mobile-safari (iPad 2 and iPhone 4) and am running into an issue with using a static menu. I've read that with the latest release of iOS 5 that **position:fixed;** is now supported in mobile-safari. However, when clicking any of the navigation links from the top navigation menu I am losing focus on the entire menu until the user starts manually scrolling the page again. I am using a combination of jQuery .ScrollTo and .localScroll plugins to achieve a smooth scroll effect while the navigation menu stays fixed at the top of the page.

Is there a simple way to regain focus of the navigation menu once a link has been clicked and the scrolling animation has completed?

To see the issue in action please visit the URL listed below. Please test on an iPhone or iPad running iOS 5 to get the explained results.

http://www.go2mktg.com

Any help with this bug would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: the website you posted seems to work fine now. would you mind sharing your solution? thx

Answer (score 1):

@xon1c.  I checked out @negrelja's page and saw some plug-ins (http://www.go2mktg.com/js/iscroll.js, specifically) which seemed to fix the issue, but I found a different solution by adding 1px to body height.  I haven't seen any issues with page jumping as the scroll bar isn't visible unless you're finger is moving the document.

I ran the code below within a completion callback function in the smooth scrolling plug-in I'm using. (library is jQuery, tested on iPad iOs5)

```
    var newBodyHeight = $('body').height() + 1;

    $('body').css({
        height: newBodyHeight
    });
```